# How to process documents in batch while not timing out on node mongodb cursor

Tags: node.js, performance, mongodb

The scenario I have is say I have 2 million documents in mongo and I want to process it in batch of say 100 or 1000 (coz the v8 memory is scarce ) and after reading the batch size of the documents I want to do some computation and write it to a file which might take longer than 10 minutes before I come and get the next set of batch size documents. How can I do that with node.js mongo db driver?

I couldn't find all the methods I need in node.js mongo db driver.for example mongo shell has docs.leftInTheBatch which tells how many documents are left in the current batch and this is not available in node.js.

Another important functionality I was looking for in node.js mongo db driver is how to set the cursor to not timeout (This is possible in mongo shell and other language drivers but I am not sure on node.js)?

```
   var hash_map = {}; 
    db.collection(collection_name).find().batchSize(100).each(function(err, docs) {
        docs.each(function(err, doc) {
            var id = doc._id; // assume this is a string not objectID
            hash_map[id] = doc.key1;
        })
        // This async function would take say 20 minutes or just assume it takes long time. now, would the cursor time out before I retrieve the next batch?
        async.series([ 
            prcocessData.bind(null, hash_map),
            writeDataToFile
        ], function(err){
           if(err) throw err;
           return callback();
        });
    });
```

Comment: No code here so how do people really diagnose what the problem here is? If you are getting timeouts then you are doing something wrong. But without the code we cannot tell exactly what you are doing wrong. So if you want help then post your code.

Comment: I haven't ran my code but based on what I read on cursor timeouts in mongo doc http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/cursors/ it says the cursor will time out after 10 minutes of inactivity. And I need processing time of greater than 10 minutes between every subsequent batch. so I am wondering how all this can be possible given the async nature of node.js. I am still trying to figure out the road map to solve this problem but more importantly do you understand my question clearly as stated above? Do you have any suggestions on how I should approach? Let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: @NeilLunn posted my code.

Comment: Still don't get it. What is the second `.each()` call? Looks like an external library, certainly nothing to do with the driver. That and your `.series()` call. Which you don't seem to understand do not execute after the former is finished. Welcome to event driven programming. Explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @NeilLunn I am just trying to read documents in batch size of 100 or 1000 because I have 2 million documents in my mongo database to process. can you please tell me how to do that first maybe? Also like I said please imagine there is a function that takes batchsize documents and process it for a long time and then go back again and read the next batch size documents. so my goal here is since there is a function in between subsequent batch reads that takes long time to process (perhaps running some in memory algorithm) I wonder if cursor would timeout when I come back again and read next batch?

Answer (score 3):

This is a wrong interpretation of the usage of "batchSize". All that means ( and essentially as a parameter to the the cursor return of `.find()`, despite the driver method ) is that that server will return a "batch" of 100 results ( in this case ) at a time, which is then to be iterated as a "cursor".

You are missing the concept of a "cursor". You do not "actually" return a "data" result that contains `100` records or "collection items" in the overall result. You just have a "pointer" that allows you to "fetch" a single "record/document" at a time on a `.next()` method.

Convenience methods like `.each()` and `.toArray()` are meant for "small" result sets where the results are basically "transformed" into an array for further processing. Either manually via `.toArray()` or implicitly via methods like `.each()`.

For large result sets you want the "stream" API provided by node and the MongoDB driver. See [**here**](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html#stream) in the documenation for how to invoke that on current versions.

Newer releases of the MongoDB node driver will return a [**node stream**](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) interface by default.

Point being that you "could" use cursor modifier such as `.limit()` here and "loop" the  results in "pages", but in you context this is not the most efficient way. Look into the streaming API as referenced by the links.

Comment: using the stream api how do I read x amount of documents at a time?

Comment: @KantKodali The beauty here is that you don't. Or that you otherwise just "callback" on the event when you have received "X" documents and then process. Otherwise you use `.limit()` and explicitly loop and change the query conditions to "exclude" those results you already read. Badly done with `.skip()`. My point is that you are missing the point. You don't process like you think you do and that "batchSize" is the wrong way to do that anyway. Use streams and call other events on every "X" documents. There is plenty of documentation as well as many posts from myself that explain this.

Comment: The reason why I got into this whole batch size thing is that I know that I have to process 2 Million documents and obviously I cannot bring all of them into memory because of the hard memory limit issues by V8 which 1.5GB for 64-bit. I have tried using skip and limit inside a for loop and yes you are right it is bad. I was going over 1.5GB so I thought I have to process X amount of docs at a time.

Comment: Since you are saying to emit another event when I receive X amount of docs and pass the callback to that event I think should also make use of .resume and .pause() which says it will stop emitting data events however any data that is available will be stores in the internal buffer. so I am worried about memory again because I need to so some computation with those X amount of docs which will take a longer time meanwhile I am worried that the internal buffer will be filled up by rest of the docs.

Comment: @KantKodali You are still so not reading the answer for what it is. You were doing it wrong. So use the streaming API as recommended. That's your fix. If you have other questions then post other questions in context so we can answer them properly.